# Socket Ids are unstable in the room

Tags: websocket, socket.io, socket.io-redis

When the clients join the room initially for a few seconds they can able to talk but after a few seconds client 1 socket id suddenly drops out from the room and getting new socket id.

After that suddenly there is a drop of the socket id of the second client and coming up with the new id.

Because of this, there is instability in the room clients are unable to communicate in the application.

We are using socket.io adapter 5.4.0v to resolve this could anyone help on this?

```
0|www  |   email: 'abc@xyz.com' }
0|www  | kq0ITfQLn9ODSEGpAAAB   abc@xyz.com   61155233238
0|www  | kq0ITfQLn9ODSEGpAAAB  joined
0|www  | group event =={"_id":"5fdc4e4666849568334b6192","name":"krishna","email":"abc@xyz.com","password":"3f133f00aa4fcf85d3a15f97d6630e7b46167c45","verification_code":656137,"verification_code_expiry":"2020-12-18T06:52:58.000Z","signup_type":"general","meeting_id":"2774581974","meeting_password":"8iysCL","user_type_id":2,"status":"Active","created_by":null,"created_on":"2020-12-18T06:37:58.000Z","updated_by":null,"updated_on":"2020-12-18T06:38:23.000Z"}
0|www  | [ 'kq0ITfQLn9ODSEGpAAAB' ]
0|www  | zVS1eE07hmUAUDazAAAC   abcd@gmail.com   6115521238
0|www  | zVS1eE07hmUAUDazAAAC  joined
0|www  | l2T0nntZ_AsP5NGmAAAD   qqweerrttyy@qqwerty.com   6115521238
0|www  | l2T0nntZ_AsP5NGmAAAD  joined
0|www  | group event =={"participantName":"Krishna","meetingID":"6115521238","message":"hello\n"}
0|www  | [ 'kq0ITfQLn9ODSEGpAAAB', 'l2T0nntZ_AsP5NGmAAAD' ]
0|www  | group event =={"participantName":"qqqqq","meetingID":"6115521238","message":"E\n"}
0|www  | [ 'kq0ITfQLn9ODSEGpAAAB', 'WV0qlEBEvrn0AhmiAAAE' ]
0|www  | Personal event ==
0|www  | [ 'kq0ITfQLn9ODSEGpAAAB', 'WV0qlEBEvrn0AhmiAAAE' ]

0|www  | [ 'kq0ITfQLn9ODSEGpAAAB', 'WV0qlEBEvrn0AhmiAAAE' ]

0|www  | [ 'kq0ITfQLn9ODSEGpAAAB' ]
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to share your personal email address in your examples? I would change that to a generic example like `abc@xyz.com`.

Comment: that is not a problem those are not real one I changed them